# D3 scales - why does multiplying by 1 make a difference?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a retirement calculator/bar chart with d3.js. I built the bar chart to display a static array, and then connected the chart to my retirement equation.

When I connected my chart to my calculator, my yScale was wrong even though the input arrays were the same. I fixed it by changing this:

`const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, d3.max(fvArr,(d)=>d[1])]).range([height-padding,0]);`

to this:

`const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, d3.max(fvArr,(d)=>d[1]*1)]).range([height-padding,0]);`

Why did this work? Codepen is [here](https://codepen.io/curtisearlmorgan/pen/gZXzwa).

Comment: Your example Codepen link is invalid

Comment: looks like some conversion. What is the `typeof d[1]`? If it is a string maybe `Number(d[1])` will fix it.

Comment: Your pen is probably https://codepen.io/curtisearlmorgan/pen/gZXzwa. Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your data contains **strings**, not numbers.

If you look at the `fvArr` array you'll see this:

```
[[0, "30000"], [1, "32800"], [2, "35768"] etc...]
```

So, what the multiplication is doing here is just coercing the result to a number. Check this:

```js
console.log(typeof("5" * 1))
```

That is the same of using the unary plus, which is way more common:

```js
console.log(typeof(+"5"))
```